# unable to use multiple future of Boolean type in Scala

Tags: scala, future, for-comprehension

I have three `Futures` whose return type is Boolean but i am getting a compile time error saying:

> type mismatch; found : Boolean required: String

Here is my code:

```
val f1 = Future {  false }
val f2 = Future {  true }
val f3 = Future {  false }
val result = for {
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- f2
  r3 <- f3
} yield (r1 + r2 + r3)
```

Getting the error on this line

```
yield (r1 + r2 + r3)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Instead of using `yield (r1 + r2 + r3)`  change it to `yield (r1, r2, r3)` because you cannot Add Boolean.

Answer (score 4):

`r1`, `r2`, `r3` are `Boolean`s. You are trying to add them.

How are you going to add `Boolean`s?

Do you mean

```
val result: Future[Boolean] = for {
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- f2
  r3 <- f3
} yield r1 && r2 && r3
```

or

```
val result: Future[Boolean] = for {
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- f2
  r3 <- f3
} yield r1 || r2 || r3
```

or

```
val result: Future[(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)] = for {
  r1 <- f1
  r2 <- f2
  r3 <- f3
} yield (r1, r2, r3)
```

?